# I had a sex dream and didn't ejaculate

Tags: sawm, ramadan, ghusl, dream, nocturnal-emission

I had a sex dream last night (there was no penetration but there was other sexual activities). There was no orgasm during the dream and when I woke up, I didn't find anything on my clothes, so basically I didn't ejaculate.
My question is, do I have to take a shower(ghusl) even though I didn't ejaculate? Just because I had a dream about something sexual? If I don't take a shower, will that break my fast?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a wet dream does not have any effect on fasting at all. It only effects your ritual purity for purposes like prayer, and ritual purity is not a condition for observing a fast.

Secondly, if you saw a dream but did not find any traces of fluid, then you do not need to perform ghusl.

> عن الرجل يرى أنه قد احتلم، ولا يرى بللًا، فقال: لا غسل عليه
>
> He was asked about a person who remembered that he had a sexual dream but did not find moisture. He replied: Ghusl is not necessary for him.
>
> <sup>— [Sunan Abi Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/1/236)</sup>